# Would Doubly Special Relativity or Mach's Principle allow faster-than-light travel to occur without violating causality?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, causality, machs-principle

Doubly Special Relativity posits that the Planck length is the same in all reference frames. Mach's Principle posits inertia is produced by the combined mass of the universe.

From my limited understanding of Relativity, this would mean in both these theories that there would be a preferred reference frame that maintained causality as long as travel was intra-universal.

Is this true?